# How to get local variables array with firefox/firebug/chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

Does firefox/firebug/chrome debugger provides api for getting array of local variables in console? Or there is some software that provides api like that?

Comment: Well, the debugging protocol that the devtools/firebug use does provide this API, yes. But what are you actually needing this for? You don't want to write your own debugger, do you?

Comment: You can simply inspect the *scope* in the debugger, but not programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables, as in those scoped within a function?

No, you wouldnt be able to view those unless you expose them from within the function using `this` or `prototype`

EDIT: More information

```
function Car(color){ this.color = color; }
var myCar = new Car("red");
myCar.color // This would output red, and if myCar was globally defined you could view it.
```